# Decompress and read Dukascopy .bi5 tick files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, lzma, bi5

I need to open a `.bi5` file and read the contents to cut a long story short. The problem: I have tens of thousands of `.bi5` files containing time-series data that I need to decompress and process (read, dump into pandas).

I ended up installing Python 3 (I use 2.7 normally) specifically for the `lzma` library, as I ran into compiling nightmares using the `lzma` back-ports for Python 2.7, so I conceded and ran with Python 3, but with no success. The problems are too numerous to divulge, no one reads long questions!

I have included one of the `.bi5` files, if someone could manage to get it into a Pandas Dataframe and show me how they did it, that would be ideal.

ps the fie is only a few kb, it will download in a second. Thanks very much in advance.

(The file)
http://www.filedropper.com/13hticks

Comment: Do you know the format of the original data? Is it for example: (int, int, int, float, float) in each line?

Comment: 32-bit integer: milliseconds since epoch, 32-bit float: Ask price, 32-bit float: Bid price, 32-bit float: Ask volume, 32-bit float: Bid volume. There is a C++ library out there specifically for this task, but I need to work from Python. You can look at it here https://github.com/ninety47/dukascopy

Comment: Python 2.7 that is.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The code below should do the trick. First, it opens a file and decodes it in [lzma](https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html) and then uses [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to unpack the binary data.

```
import lzma
import struct
import pandas as pd


def bi5_to_df(filename, fmt):
    chunk_size = struct.calcsize(fmt)
    data = []
    with lzma.open(filename) as f:
        while True:
            chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
            if chunk:
                data.append(struct.unpack(fmt, chunk))
            else:
                break
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return df
```

The most important thing is to know the right format. I googled around and tried to guess and `'>3i2f'` (or `>3I2f`) works quite good. (It's big endian 3 ints 2 floats. What you suggest: `'i4f'` doesn't produce sensible floats - regardless whether big or little endian.) For `struct` and format syntax see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html).

```
df = bi5_to_df('13h_ticks.bi5', '>3i2f')
df.head()
Out[177]: 
      0       1       2     3     4
0   210  110218  110216  1.87  1.12
1   362  110219  110216  1.00  5.85
2   875  110220  110217  1.00  1.12
3  1408  110220  110218  1.50  1.00
4  1884  110221  110219  3.94  1.00
```

---

**Update**

To compare the output of `bi5_to_df` with https://github.com/ninety47/dukascopy,
I compiled and run `test_read_bi5` from there. The first lines of the output are:

```
time, bid, bid_vol, ask, ask_vol
2012-Dec-03 01:00:03.581000, 131.945, 1.5, 131.966, 1.5
2012-Dec-03 01:00:05.142000, 131.943, 1.5, 131.964, 1.5
2012-Dec-03 01:00:05.202000, 131.943, 1.5, 131.964, 2.25
2012-Dec-03 01:00:05.321000, 131.944, 1.5, 131.964, 1.5
2012-Dec-03 01:00:05.441000, 131.944, 1.5, 131.964, 1.5
```

And `bi5_to_df` on the same input file gives:

```
bi5_to_df('01h_ticks.bi5', '>3I2f').head()
Out[295]: 
      0       1       2     3    4
0  3581  131966  131945  1.50  1.5
1  5142  131964  131943  1.50  1.5
2  5202  131964  131943  2.25  1.5
3  5321  131964  131944  1.50  1.5
4  5441  131964  131944  1.50  1.5
```

So everything seems to be fine (ninety47's code reorders columns).

Also, it's probably more accurate to use `'>3I2f'` instead of `'>3i2f'` (i.e. `unsigned int` instead of `int`).

Comment: It looks plausible ptrj. The 1st column is supposed to be a timestamp, but if you are correct, and that is a true representation of the data I will have to take the initial timestamp from the dated folder structure and add to it (long story). I will check it out tomorrow just to be sure, but it looks like you banked the bounty. Speak soon.

Comment: The first columns is "miliseconds since epoch". If you run `pd.TimedeltaIndex(df[0], 'ms')`, you'll see that it covers 1 hour. To get the timestamps, do for example `ts + pd.TimedeltaIndex(df[0], 'ms')` where `ts` is your timestamp.

Comment: the first two columns are supposed to be floats though. It's the price of a currency (EURUSD). Would there be any chance that it has been compressed this way, to save space perhaps?

Comment: When I say the first two columns, I mean the first two columns after the milliseconds, so that would be the second and third to be clear. Or `1` and `2` this case.

Comment: I am going with the answer regardless, it's just a case of munging from here. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @ajsp These two columns indeed look like the EURUSD prices * 10000. And if I'm not mistaken it's always `df[1] > df[2]`. I doubt it's a matter of space - maybe rather the resolution of prices matters.

Comment: the convention is usually to put the bid price before the ask price which would normally result in `df[1] < df[2]`, where the difference between is the spread, but that's not even a consideration at this point, I suppose it's down to broker preference, or whoever captures their data for them in this case. Anyway thanks for your efforts, much appreciated.

Comment: @ajsp Glad I could help. See also the update - comparison with ninety47's C++ code.

Comment: Thank you @ptrj. The only thing, how to transform columns 1 and 2 so that they show the decimals as wel? Here is a example: from your function i get this number 7106260 but the actual price is 7106,26

Comment: @RaduS Not sure what you mean. You can simply divide the numbers in both columns by 100, for example `df.iloc[:, [1, 2]] = df.iloc[:, [1, 2]] / 100`. For this currency pair the factor is 100. It can be different for another pair - it's not encoded in the input file - you have ot know it.

Comment: thank you @ptrj; i just realized that my question was a bit stupid. Of course, i just had to divide it :)

Answer (score 3):

```
import requests
import struct
from lzma import LZMADecompressor, FORMAT_AUTO

# for download compressed EURUSD 2020/06/15/10h_ticks.bi5 file
res = requests.get("https://www.dukascopy.com/datafeed/EURUSD/2020/06/15/10h_ticks.bi5", stream=True)
print(res.headers.get('content-type'))

rawdata = res.content

decomp = LZMADecompressor(FORMAT_AUTO, None, None)
decompresseddata = decomp.decompress(rawdata)

firstrow = struct.unpack('!IIIff', decompresseddata[0: 20])
print("firstrow:", firstrow)
# firstrow: (436, 114271, 114268, 0.9399999976158142, 0.75)
# time = 2020/06/15/10h + (1 month) + 436 milisecond

secondrow = struct.unpack('!IIIff', decompresseddata[20: 40])
print("secondrow:", secondrow)
# secondrow: (537, 114271, 114267, 4.309999942779541, 2.25)

# time = 2020/06/15/10h + (1 month) + 537 milisecond
# ask = 114271 / 100000 = 1.14271
# bid = 114267 / 100000 = 1.14267
# askvolume = 4.31
# bidvolume = 2.25

# note that 00 -> is january
# "https://www.dukascopy.com/datafeed/EURUSD/2020/00/15/10h_ticks.bi5" for january
# "https://www.dukascopy.com/datafeed/EURUSD/2020/01/15/10h_ticks.bi5" for february

#  iterating
print(len(decompresseddata), int(len(decompresseddata) / 20))
for i in range(0, int(len(decompresseddata) / 20)):
    print(struct.unpack('!IIIff', decompresseddata[i * 20: (i + 1) * 20]))
```

Comment: Thanks for that, much appreciated, do you know how often they update their feed by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm re-opening an old thread, but if someone needs to know what the structure of .bi5 file is, find it [here](https://medium.com/@tomas.rampas/the-dukascopy-tick-data-demystified-3af1da80e6c5). Hope even after those years somebody'd find it helpful.

> The bi5 structure background
> The size of one tick record in a bi5 file is 5 × 4 bytes. These bytes carry the timestamp, bid and ask quotes, and tick volume for both quote sides. The structure of the bi5 record is the following:
>
> `1st 4 bytes → The time part of the timestamp`
>
> `2nd 4 bytes → Bid`
>
> `3rd 4 bytes → Ask`
>
> `4th 4 bytes → Bid Volume`
>
> `5th 4 bytes → Ask Volume`
>
> The timestamp is not date and time, but actually, it’s a count of milliseconds from the starting hour of the file. The bytes must also be uncompressed first, and then reverted during translation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using numpy as to parse the data before transfer it to pandas. Maybe is a long way solution, but I will allow you to manipulate and clean the data before you made the analysis in Panda, also the integration between them are pretty straight forward,

Answer (score 0):

In case someone used endpoint
https://datafeed.dukascopy.com/datafeed/EURUSD/2022/11/06/BID_candles_min_1.bi5

the format is '>IIIIIf' (big endian, 5x integer, 1x float )
and the columns are Seconds, O, H, L, C, V