# read Dukascopy .bi5 ohlc tick files

Tags: python-3.x, bi5

I want to decode and read `.bi5` file which is downloaded from the Dukascopy website.

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176164/decompress-and-read-dukascopy-bi5-tick-files) but unfortunately the suggested python code no longer produces valid output because the data file itself has been changed. This is the final output of `.bi5` ohlc [tick file](https://www.filedropper.com/showdownload.php/00hticks) (`time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume`):

```
31.10.2018 00:00:00.000,1.13452,1.13452,1.13452,1.13452,3
31.10.2018 00:00:01.000,1.13450,1.13450,1.13450,1.13450,6.56
31.10.2018 00:00:02.000,1.13450,1.13450,1.13450,1.13450,3.44
31.10.2018 00:00:03.000,1.13450,1.13451,1.13449,1.13451,13.35
31.10.2018 00:00:04.000,1.13451,1.13451,1.13451,1.13451,1.31
31.10.2018 00:00:05.000,1.13451,1.13451,1.13451,1.13451,1.25
31.10.2018 00:00:06.000,1.13452,1.13452,1.13452,1.13452,1
```

The file is no longer in the `3i2f` format. What would be the `struct` format of this file? I know that instead of `2f` it now has 5 float values (`5f`) but what about the time?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*I was looking for the same information to no avail so posting the answer here despite question being 8 months old.*

Oddly the time and ohlc are integers, only volume is float.

Time is an offset from midnight in seconds.

```
In [118]:bi5_to_df('20100101.bi5', '>5if').head(5)
Out[118]:
     0       1       2       3       4          5
0    0  143283  143267  143267  143283  74.300003
1   60  143268  143284  143268  143285  25.400000
2  120  143280  143280  143268  143280  30.900000
3  180  143280  143273  143268  143280  41.900002
4  240  143283  143277  143277  143283  53.799999
```